# Javascript: Text Replace for multiple strings in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have an array with Twitter hashtags. And I want to filter a string `tw.text` for those hashtags and wrap the words in a `span`

```
var hashtags = new Array("home","car", "tree");

tw.text.replace('#home', '<span class="hash">#home</span>')
```

How would I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hashtags.forEach(function (elem) {
    tw.text = tw.text.replace('#' + elem, '<span class="hash">#' + elem + "</span>");
});
```

This does not account for tags that contain other tags which could lead to duplicate replacement.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, is there also a simple way to check for the "uppercase" version of the words as well? Like `HOME, CAR, TREE`?

Comment: I think you could use `new RegExp('#' + elem, 'i')` and then `.replace(regexp, '<span...>#\0</span>')`

Answer (score 3):

I would build a regex to do the replacements like this...

```
var hashtags = new Array("home","car", "tree");

var rex = new RegExp("#("+hashtags.join("|")+")",'g')

tw.text.replace(rex, '<span class="$1">#$1</span>')
```

Regex ends up being `#(thing|another|etc...)` so all replacements are done in one pass.

Comment: Thank you, see my comment on the other answer. In a rex the check for the pure uppercase version should be easier i guess. However I have no idea how to?

Comment: well, the `i` switch makes the regex case insensitive, meaning it matches `HoMe` and `home` and `HOME`. You would add the flag to the second parameter, which already sets the `g` for global flag, when building the regex... `new RegExp('...','gi')`